# JTable cell span merge

Tags: java, swing, merge, jtable, html

Hi I'm having a problem with Java JTable. I want to merge or span cells. I did it using this examples:

http://www.java3z.com/cwbwebhome/article/article5/swing_example/JTableExamples4.html
 (last 2 ones)

It works but the header and the cells width are not the same size. The problem agravates when there are more 20 columns, the last cells appear just half. Does anyone know how to solve this problem of synchronizing cells and headers? Does anyone have another CellSpan example/way?

If someone try to run this examples will get StackOverFlow error,to solve, justo change this line: *setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);* to   *columnIdentifiers = columnNames;* at AttributiveCellTableModel class. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same example is available [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/MultiSpanCellTableExample.htm). It seems the problem might be in `MultiSpanCellTable` `getCellRect()` implementation. Column margin is contributing to the cell width and generating this offset. Looks like the problem goes away if you replace:

```
cellFrame.width = aColumn.getWidth() + columnMargin;
```

with:

```
cellFrame.width = aColumn.getWidth();
```