# How to merge rows in a JTable dynamically?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

[image]

I want to merge rows as shown in the `JTable`.  I have no idea about row merging.  I am using `DefaultTableModel` for rendering data from DB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JTable cell span merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588462/jtable-cell-span-merge), also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856733/how-to-merge-cell-in-defaulttablemodel-jtable)

Comment: I did not get any idea from code and getting StatckOverFlow error while running above mensioned example.Can u explain the points

Comment: In related links you can find that problem and possible solutions

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help. That's complicated to solve problems without code.

Comment: I copy [code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/MultiSpanCellTableExample.htm) then fix `StackOverflowError` like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21977825/2894369) and all work fine. Also you can try [that](https://code.google.com/p/spantable/source/browse/SpanTable/src/main/java/spantable/?r=b5aa2f0d7bc6e0ced427562dcc22396b41963948)

Comment: Is there any easy way to do this.Can you add description to this example